# Como faço para tratar mensagem com caracteres especiais

Tags: c#, .net, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou consumindo um serviço REST que esta retornando a seguinte mensagem com caracteres especiais:

"EspÃ©cie T&iacute;tulo Inv&aacute;lida"

É possivel tratar essa mensagem?

Comment: Isso é problema da codificação enviada/recebida. Poste o código que está usando para ler as mensagens recebidas.

Comment: webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
          dsretorno.ReadXml(responseStream);
        return dsretorno;

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar com o Encoding, verifique se isso resolve seu problema:

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Comment: Já tinha feito isso e não resolveu.